# Sitecore Azure Deployment error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-azure

I have started sitecore deployment using Sitecore Azure module, and getting below error message:

> 'Sitecore_Core' - Create Database failed System.ApplicationException:
>   'Sitecore_Core' - Create Database failed --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   edition at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object
>   argument, String argumentName) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.CreateDatabase.CreateAzureDatabase(String
>   connectionString, String name, String edition, String size) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.CreateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__c()
>   at Sitecore.Azure.Retryer.Retryer.ExecuteNoResult(Action action,
>   Action recover) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.CreateDatabase.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase
>   args) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase
>   args)

Also, do i need to created core, master & web database manually in Azure or the deployment itself will create all these databases? I can see new storage account and SQL DB server has been created by the deployment process itself.

Please help and let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore Azure must create Azure SQL Database service automatically for Sitecore Core, Master and Web databases and transfer data from your local SQL Server databases to the cloud ones.

What is Sitecore Azure version you are using?

If you wish you can manually exported Sitecore databases to your own Azure SQL Database service, and then force the module to use them. Please check the following article for more details: https://github.com/olegburov/sitecore-azure-content/blob/master/articles/how-to-use-a-custom-azure-sql-databases-service-in-sitecore-azure.md

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says it failed because the `edition` parameter is null when passing to the `CreateDatabase.CreateAzureDatabase(String connectionString, String name, String edition, String size)` method. The module takes the value from the `\Website\App_Config\AzureVendors\Microsoft.xml` file, which is automatically updated.

Delete the `Microsoft.xml` file and then restart Sitecore to force the module download the latest version. if you open it you must see the `<tiers>` element with the following sub elements:

- `<tier name="Basic">`
- `<tier name="Standard">`
- `<tier name="Premium">`